# How to show X.509 certificate details in Silverlight?

Tags: .net, silverlight, x509certificate

In a .NET 4 backend we have an X.509 certificate, in the form of an instance of [`X509Certificate2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.aspx) or [`X509Certificate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate.aspx).  In its Silverlight frontend we want to display the details of that certificate.

In .NET we could simply use [`X509Certificate2UI`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2ui.aspx) for this, which brings up the standard Windows certificate details dialog.  (**Update:** This dialog can show any `X509Certificate2` instance, regardless where it came from.)  But that class is not available in Silverlight.  (Note that also `X509Certificate2` is not available in Silverlight, but [`X509Certificate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate%28VS.95%29.aspx) is.)

The only way I currently see is to send an instance of `X509Certificate` to the frontend (**update**: I know how to do that), and build our own Silverlight UI on top of that information.

My question: Is there a simpler way, or is such a UI already available from somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the lack of positive reponses, I concluded that the simplest option is to build our own UI on top of an [`X509Certificate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate%28VS.95%29.aspx) instance.  For a *very* simple implementation, call [`X509Certificate.ToString(true)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s62tkfx8%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) (or the equivalent on `X509Certicate2` on the server side) and just display the resulting text to the user.  The result isn't really user friendly, but at least all information is there.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a Com automation object in .Net that invokes X509Certificate2UI, run your Silverlight app fulltrust, and use AutomationFactory.CreateObject to invoke that object.

Note: The security context under which the com object is invoked might be different than your user's security context; you might need to set security for the certificate appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

As I remember X509Certificate2UI shows you the windows certificate dialog which can also be accessed via the microsoft management console snap in "certificates".

I'd guess that it can only show local certificates. And because of the silverlight security restrictions I'd also guess that event this is not possible (while running as webapplication).

But please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Yes, `X509Certificate2UI` shows the standard Windows certificate dialog.  But it can show any certificate: on disk, in the certificate store, and also one which exists purely in memory.  So I see no security restriction why Silverlight would not be able to show this dialog.

Comment: I don't know what X509Certificate2UI exactly does. But in my opinion it executes unmanaged code into the windows os. Because of the silverlight sandbox this is not possible in silverlight. The security restrictions i've mentioned are the restrictions caused by the sandbox concept.

Answer (score 0):

You fetch the information you want to display from the asp.net application hosting the silverlight object and pass what you want to display throught the InitParams of the object and then retrieve them in the App.xaml.cs file. I am using this method to pass web service endpoint configuration. You can pass any combination of key/value.

See this msdn link for more details on the method if you are not familiar.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189004%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

Comment: This is not the answer I'm looking for, since my question is not about transporting information from ASP.NET server to the Silverlight client.  My questions is specifically about how to make a Silverlight client show the details of an X.509 certficate (i.e., an instance of `X509Certificate2` or `X509Certificate`).